# Having issues with setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the tabs feature from jQuery UI and I need to reload the tab after 5 seconds. I currently have two methods of reloading the data:

1. Automatic (jQuery/JavaScript)
2. Click link

When reloading the first time automatically and after clicking the reload link, the reload is not following the desired time of 5 seconds.

Example:

1. Enter the page - Call method for automatic reload (ok working)
2. Pass 3 seconds - Click link for reload manual (ok working)
3. Time is obeying the 5 second timeframe.

What options do I have?

Comment: can you share your relevant code?

Comment: When page is loaded you create timer with: _var refreshTimer=setTimeout(refreshFunc,5000);_ On your stage2 (manual reload), you must: _clearTimeout(refreshTimer); refreshTimer=setTimeout(refreshFunc,5000);_

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without looking the code, but it seems that you need cancel the first `setTimeout` call before call it again using the manual action.

Can you show the code?